# Sails.js unit testing getting uncaught error

Tags: sails.js, mocha.js

Being working with sails.js and i was writing test cases using MOCHA and grunt am getting Uncaught error. I searched over net but i didn't get clear solution. how to get started with sails.js unit testing?

```
1)  "before all" hook:
 Uncaught Error: listen EADDRINUSE
  at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
  at Server._listen2 (net.js:1156:14)
  at listen (net.js:1182:10)
  at Server.listen (net.js:1267:5)
  at Object.module.exports.bootstrap (config/bootstrap.js:16:3)
```

this above error am getting while running 'grunt test', thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

Actually there are two servers running so that created this issue. just kill one server it works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the question and I hope that the fix continues to work. If you would like to discuss any other Sails.js issues in realtime with other users, check out our Gitter page. https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails